# for removing the product from the cart .the remove button is not working. here i used ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, button

this is my product remove button for removing the product from the cart, I am used here     ajax :

***cart.hbs***

```
<button
  href="/remove-product"
  id="{{this.product._id}}"
  class="btn btn-danger"
  onclick="removeProduct ,('{{this.product._id}}'), confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the product   {{this.product.Name}} ?')"
>
  remove
</button>

function removeProduct(cartId, proId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/remove-product',
    data: {
      product: proId,
      cart: cartId,
    },
    method: 'post',
    success: (response) => {
      if (response.removeProduct) {
        alert('Product Removed Successfully');
        location.reload();
      } else {
        document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML = response.removeProduct;
      }
    },
  });
}
```

***user.js***
this is my js file

```
router.post('/remove-product', (req, res) => {
  userHelpers.removeProduct(req.body).then((response) => {
    res.json(response);
  });
});
```

for removing the product,
this is the cord for removing the product from the cart here , I passed proId and cartId
***user-helpers.js***

```
removeProduct: (details) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.get()
      .collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION)
      .updateOne(
        { _id: objectId(details.cart) },
        {
          $pull: { products: { item: objectId(details.product) } },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        resolve({ removeProduct: true });
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: "is not working" is a useless problem description. You need to tell us exactly what the issue is, mention errors you're getting, and you must've done exhaustive debugging yourself before posting here, so what did do to narrow down the problem?

Comment: If you do not like my description I'm sorry.

Comment: @Harshadn that was a request for you to [edit] the question and make it clear what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and _what went wrong_. Help us help you by being clear about what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Ajax, we have to be very conscious about how the data is sending.
I mean here we sending the data

```
data: {
  product: proId,
  cart: cartId,
},
```

this is the data and sending method is ***post*** so, in ***js*** file also need to use ***post method***, I have solved this problem myself
here is the code,

here is the button,
***cart.hbs***

```
<button id=" Remove" class=" btn btn-danger" onclick=" removeProduct
  ('{{this._id}}','{{this.product._id}}')"> remove</button>
                                

<script>
    function removeProduct(cartId, proId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/remove-product',
            data: {
                product: proId,
                cart: cartId,
            },
            method: 'post',
            success: (response) => {
                if (response.removeProduct) {
                    alert("Product Removed Successfully")
                    location.reload()

                } else {
                    document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML =  response.removeProduct
                                         
                }
            }
        });

    };


</script>
```

***user.js***

```
router.post('/remove-product',(req,res)=>{
  userHelpers.removeProduct(req.body).then(async(response)=>{
      res.json(response)  

   })
})
```

and this is the code for removing the product from the cart

***user-helpers.js***

```
removeProduct:(details)=>{
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
        db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION)
        .updateOne({_id:objectId(details.cart)}, 
    {

        $pull:{products:{item:objectId(details .product)}}
    }
        ).then((response)=>{

            resolve({removeProduct:true})
        })
    
  })
}
```